# grecaptcha.render does not change language

Tags: javascript, recaptcha

I explicitly render the reCAPTCHA widget, but I'm not able to change the language according to the documentation.

Here is my onloadCallback:

```
var onloadCallback = function () {

    grecaptcha.render('captcha_element', {
        'sitekey': '<mysitekey>',
        'theme' : 'light',
        'hl': 'en'
    });
};
```

I am able to change the theme, but when I change the language code nothing is happening.

Comment: I ended up adding &amp;hl=en as a parameter to the javascript resource, like this: 
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit&amp;hl=en" async defer></script>

Answer (score 3):

"hl" is not a parametr of the "render" function, so you can't use it as is in your example. See:

```
https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display#auto_render
```

If you would like to render reCaptcah2 with localized text, you have to call api.js from google

```
https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js
```

with parameter "hl" and its value for example "cs" (for Czech language), so it means:

```
https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?hl=cs
```